# Xml to a DataSet then Combine DataTables Based on Date

Tags: c#, xml, datatable, dataset

I think that another person asked a question similar to what I am trying to accomplish [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377198/xml-to-dataset-problem-finding-what-datarow-contains-a-datatable). I am trying to take an XML web response and build a DataTable with each PayCodeId and AmountInTime in rows according to their date.  Some Dates have no PayCodeIds or AmountInTime but I still need to represent that Date with a row. Here is a sample of what the xml response looks like:

```
<DailyTotals>
  <DateTotals Date="5/24/2014"/>
  <DateTotals Date="5/25/2014" GrandTotal="0.0">
    <Totals></Totals>
  </DateTotals>
  <DateTotals Date="5/26/2014" GrandTotal="13.25">
    <Totals>
      <Total PayCodeId="101" AmountInTime="5.25"/>
      <Total PayCodeId="601" AmountInTime="13.25"/>
      <Total PayCodeId="301" AmountInTime="8.0"/>
      <Total PayCodeId="602" AmountInTime="8.0"/>
    </Totals>
  </DateTotals>
  <DateTotals Date="5/27/2014"/>
  <DateTotals Date="5/28/2014" GrandTotal="0.0">
    <Totals></Totals>
  </DateTotals>
  <DateTotals Date="5/29/2014" GrandTotal="8.25">
    <Totals>
      <Total PayCodeId="101" AmountInTime="2.25"/>
      <Total PayCodeId="601" AmountInTime="8.25"/>
      <Total PayCodeId="301" AmountInTime="6.0"/>
      <Total PayCodeId="602" AmountInTime="6.0"/>
    </Totals>
  </DateTotals>
</DailyTotals>
```

Here is how I would like my DataTable to look:

```
|  Date   | | PayCode | |AmtTime|
 5/24/2014
 5/25/2014
 5/26/2014    101         5.25
 5/26/2014    601         13.25
 5/26/2014    301         8.0
 5/26/2014    602         8.0
 5/27/2014
 5/28/2014
 5/26/2014    101         2.25
 5/26/2014    601         8.25
 5/26/2014    301         6.25
 5/26/2014    602         6.25
```

I am building a DataSet from the xml response and then trying to use the tables, iterate or loop through them in someway to accomplish this.  I am having a hard time figuring out how to create new rows for the different paycodes and assign them the appropriate dates.  Here is a code snippet of what I have tried so far which does not work:

```
    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(results)))
        {

            ds.ReadXml(reader);
        }

        // Build DataTable
        dt.Columns.Add("Date");
        dt.Columns.Add("PayCodeId");
        dt.Columns.Add("AmountInTime");

        DataTable dateTotals = ds.Tables["DateTotals"];
        DataTable total = ds.Tables["Total"];

        for (int i = 0; i < dateTotals.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DataRow dr;
            object[] rowItems = new object[dt.Columns.Count];

            // Set the Date for each row item
            rowItems[0] = dateTotals.Rows[i].Field<string>("Date");

            if (dateTotals.Rows[i].Field<string>("GrandTotal") == null
                || dateTotals.Rows[i].Field<string>("GrandTotal") == "0.0")
            {
                rowItems[1] = "";
                rowItems[2] = "";
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (DataRow row in total.Rows)
                {
                    rowItems[1] = row.Field<string>("PayCodeId");
                    rowItems[2] = row.Field<string>("AmountInTime");
                }
            }

            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr.ItemArray = rowItems;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
```

I wish the xml format from the response was different but there's nothing I can do about it. Is what I am trying to accomplish possible using the DataSet and its tables?  In the other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377198/xml-to-dataset-problem-finding-what-datarow-contains-a-datatable) I was looking at it seems there may be an answer using different XmlReadMode options but it was in VB and not C#.  I am still looking into it and I will post an answer if I figure it out.  Thanks everyone for any help or suggestions and helping me learn :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link I mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377198/xml-to-dataset-problem-finding-what-datarow-contains-a-datatable) did have the answer I was looking for.  If anyone needs an answer/example of this in C# you can use this as a reference.  Here is the code that worked:

```
    // Create an XmlReader
    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(results)))
    {
        ds.ReadXml(reader);
    }

    // Build DataTable
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    dt.Columns.Add("Date");
    dt.Columns.Add("PayCodeId");
    dt.Columns.Add("AmountInTime");

    DataTable dateTotals = ds.Tables["DateTotals"];
    DataTable totals = ds.Tables["Totals"];
    DataTable total = ds.Tables["Total"];

    foreach(DataRow dateTotalsRow in dateTotals.Rows)
    {
        if (dateTotalsRow.Field<string>("GrandTotal") == null || dateTotalsRow.Field<string>("GrandTotal") == "0.0")
        {
            DataRow dr;
            object[] rowItems = new object[dt.Columns.Count];

            rowItems[0] = dateTotalsRow.Field<string>("Date");
            rowItems[1] = "";
            rowItems[2] = "";

            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr.ItemArray = rowItems;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (DataRow totalsRow in totals.Rows)
            {
                if (totalsRow.Field<int>("DateTotals_Id").ToString() == dateTotalsRow.Field<int>("DateTotals_Id").ToString())
                {
                    foreach (DataRow totalRow in total.Rows)
                    {
                        if (totalRow.Field<int>("Totals_Id").ToString() == totalsRow.Field<int>("Totals_Id").ToString())
                        {
                            DataRow dr;
                            object[] rowItems = new object[dt.Columns.Count];

                            rowItems[0] = dateTotalsRow.Field<string>("Date");
                            rowItems[1] = totalRow.Field<string>("PayCodeId");
                            rowItems[2] = totalRow.Field<string>("AmountInTime");

                            dr = dt.NewRow();
                            dr.ItemArray = rowItems;
                            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return dt;
```

The key here is that ReadXml automatically provides reference IDs to the tables.  I did not know this and learned something from this. Big thanks to Matt Wilko for his answer a few years back written in VB [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377198/xml-to-dataset-problem-finding-what-datarow-contains-a-datatable) which gave me my answer.  Belated thank you Matt!